# Is it possible for tomcat to return status code 307 (temporary redirect) instead of 302 (moved temporarily)

Tags: java, tomcat, apache-httpcomponents

I have tomcat connector in it's server.xml config file that should redirect all http traffic to https:

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
<Connector SSLEnabled="true" clientAuth="false" keystoreFile="path/to/keystore/ks.jks" keystorePass="changeit" maxThreads="150" port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

If a request is sent to non-secure port 8080, response will have status code 302. Which is fine for GET requests, but not for POST requests. Why? Because those requests are made via `RestTemplate` with `LaxRedirectStrategy` which in case of 302 transforms POST to GET, which causes exception "GET not supported...". One solution could be to extend `LaxRedirectStrategy` and override `getRedirect()` method like so:

LaxRedirectStrategy:

```
@Override
public HttpUriRequest getRedirect(final HttpRequest request,
        final HttpResponse response,final HttpContext context)
        throws ProtocolException {

    final URI uri = getLocationURI(request, response, context);
    final String method = request.getRequestLine().getMethod();

    if (method.equalsIgnoreCase(HttpHead.METHOD_NAME)) {
        return new HttpHead(uri);
    } else if (method.equalsIgnoreCase(HttpGet.METHOD_NAME)) {
        return new HttpGet(uri);
    } else {

        final int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (status == HttpStatus.SC_TEMPORARY_REDIRECT) {
            return RequestBuilder.copy(request).setUri(uri).build();
        } else {
            return new HttpGet(uri);
        }

    }

}
```

and my own implementation (extension):

ReLaxRedirectStrategy:

```
@Override
public HttpUriRequest getRedirect(final HttpRequest request,
        final HttpResponse response,final HttpContext context)
        throws ProtocolException {

    final URI uri = getLocationURI(request, response, context);
    final String method = request.getRequestLine().getMethod();

    if (method.equalsIgnoreCase(HttpHead.METHOD_NAME)) {
        return new HttpHead(uri);
    } else if (method.equalsIgnoreCase(HttpGet.METHOD_NAME)) {
        return new HttpGet(uri);
    } else {

        final int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (status == HttpStatus.SC_TEMPORARY_REDIRECT
            || status == HttpStatus.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY) { // HERE IS THE DIFFERENCE

            return RequestBuilder.copy(request).setUri(uri).build();
        } else {
            return new HttpGet(uri);
        }

    }

}
```

I was wondering if there's a way to make tomcat return 307 instead of 302 to avoid code overriding and possible errors in case Apache's httpcomponents get updated in the future.

**EDIT #1** I'll probably end up with version 2 of `ReLaxRedirectStrategy` if I don't find a better solution:

ReLaxRedirectStrategyV2:

```
@Override
public HttpUriRequest getRedirect(final HttpRequest request,
        final HttpResponse response,final HttpContext context)
        throws ProtocolException {

    final String method = request.getRequestLine().getMethod();
    final int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

    if (method.equalsIgnoreCase(HttpPost.METHOD_NAME)
        && status == HttpStatus.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY) {

        final URI uri = getLocationURI(request, response, context);
        return RequestBuilder.copy(request).setUri(uri).build();
    } else {
        return super.getRedirect(request, response, context);
    }

}
```

This way overridden code is minimal. If response to POST request has status 302, code will do what I want, else it will do whatever is defined in superclass.

Comment: The request comes in unsecured and is redirected to ssl after that?

Comment: Yes, but POST is transformed to GET if I don't override `getRedirect()` method.

Comment: why not change the rest client to use directly the secure channel and not expose at all the insecure one ?

Comment: @Thierry One of requirements is that HTTPS is used only in production. If I change REST client, then HTTPS must be used in dev environment too. I'll ask PM if that requirement is really necessary. If not, I'll probably go the route you suggested: send all requests to secure channel without redirection.

Comment: Make it configurable : use http only for dev and integ, and https only for pre-prod and production. This way you don't have to redirect, and don't have to cope with certificates too early. I strongly advise to have the same configuration on preprod than the one on prod (https).